# compare just time part from datetime in kql

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to compare just the time part of different datetimes.

the result gives me false, but it should be true. what am I missing here?
is there a better way to do it.

this is what I tried, and the logic seems to fail:

````
let current_future = format_datetime(now(+2h), 'HH:m:s.fff');
//print current_future
let current_past = format_datetime(now(-1h), 'HH:m:s.fff');
//print current_past
let result = iff((todatetime(current_past) < todatetime(current_future)), "true", "false");
print result ```
````

Comment: Please fix the example

Comment: was fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

To extract the time from a datetime value, you should do `% 1d`.

```
let x = datetime(2022-01-23 09:55:16);
let y = datetime(2022-01-21 19:55:16);
print x<y, (x%1d) < (y%1d)
```

Result:

| print_0 | print_1 |
| --- | --- |
| False | True |

Answer (score 1):

You could use timespan.

```
let t1 = datetime(2022-01-01 23:44:55);
let t2 = datetime(2022-02-01 08:22:33);
print (t1 - bin(t1,1d)) < (t2 - bin(t2,1d))
```

Your solution is problematic since you are not using 2 digits hour and alphabetically '8' (like in 8:22:33) is bigger than '23' (like in 23:44:55)